# How to open file that updated every week?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm basic to VBA macro. I want to make button that everytime I click, it open the file with specific weeknumber.

Current week of the year = 29 march 2018 = week 13

At 2 April, I want this code automatically the file at week 14. How do I get there?

```
Sub refresh()

    Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
      "C:\Users\GMM\Desktop\weekly report\SUMMARY 2018\WK13 2018\WK13SUMMARY.xlsm" _
      , Notify:=False
    Windows("board (002) protect.xlsm").Activate
End Sub
```

I want `WK13 2018\WK13SUMMARY.xlsm` become `WK("ww") 2018\WK("ww")SUMMARY.xlsm`

and in week 14, it will automatically become `WK14 2018\WK14SUMMARY.xlsm`

Comment: Be aware that WeekNum is not matching european standards. If you need them use the [VBA.Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications#Colombia%20(Espa%C3%B1ol)) function which has more options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the code below to automate the file name, and also the folder name (I saw it changes according to the Week's date as well).

***Code***

```
Option Explicit

Sub refresh()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim wbName As String
Dim LastFolderName As String

' get the file name of current week
wbName = "WK" & WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(Date) & "SUMMARY.xlsm"

' last folder's name according to current week and year
LastFolderName = "WK" & WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(Date) & " " & Year(Date)

Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Users\GMM\Desktop\weekly report\SUMMARY 2018\" & _
                        LastFolderName & "\" & wbName, Notify:=False)

wb.Activate ' <-- not sure why you would nee to Activate it

End Sub
```

Comment: Might be worth just getting the week number in a variable and using that directly in **`Workbooks.Open`** statement as rest of the text is static?

Comment: @Zac probabely, but then again the options are endless, I don't want to go too much with the answer, so the **PO** won't get lost

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [WorksheetFunction.WeekNum Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheetfunction-weeknum-method-excel) to get the weeknumber of a date:

```
WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(Date)
```

returns the weeknumber of today's date.

Answer (score 0):

try with below

```
Sub refresh()
    Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
      "C:\Users\GMM\Desktop\weekly report\SUMMARY 2018\" & "WK" & WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(Now()) & " 2018\" & "WK" & WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(Now()) & "SUMMARY.xlsm" _
      , Notify:=False
    Windows("board (002) protect.xlsm").Activate
End Sub
```